# Setting variables in expect script has no effect

Tags: macos, expect

I'm trying to write a script to get a password from my Mac keychain and use it to add a password protected key to the keychain (using `ssh-add`). It's meant to be part of a collection of scripts that get sourced by zsh. Currently my scripts looks like this

```
cat <<EOF | expect -d

set password [exec /usr/bin/security find-generic-password -s SSH -w]
puts "$password"

spawn -noecho /usr/bin/ssh-add $::env(HOME)/.ssh/id_ecdsa

expect -timeout 3 "Enter passphrase for"
send "$password\r"

interact

EOF
```

The `puts "$password"` is purely there for debug purposes. And I get the following results

```
$ source .zshrc.d/090_ssh_keys
Password:
Enter passphrase for /Users/james.dominy/.ssh/id_ecdsa:
$ ssh-add -l
The agent has no identities.
```

As you can see, the password variable isn't being set; I've tried changing the variable name, and as a debugging effort, I've tried setting it to a number (`set password 1`) and to a string literal (`set password "a"`) but those don't work either. However, if I cut and paste this into an interactive expect session, everything works as expected

```
expect1.1> set password [exec /usr/bin/security find-generic-password -s SSH -w]
**********
expect1.2> puts $password
**********
expect1.3> spawn -noecho /usr/bin/ssh-add $::env(HOME)/.ssh/id_ecdsa
89080
expect1.4> expect -timeout 3 "Enter passphrase for"
Enter passphrase for /Users/sirlark/.ssh/id_ecdsa: expect1.5> send "$password\r"
expect1.6> interact

Identity added: /Users/sirlark/.ssh/id_ecdsa (sirlark main ssh key)
expect1.7> %
```

Password obscured obviously, but this works. Why?

Comment: Your here-doc is unquoted, so the **shell** is substituting those variable **before** handing the here-doc to `cat`. Use `cat << 'EOF'` with the single quotes.

Comment: @glennjackman Yup, that did it. Thanks. If you make that an answer, I'll accept.